# AppHarbor c# 4.6.1 higher version than exists in current target framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, appharbor, .net-4.6.1, discord.net

I've added my source code to github using the plugin for visual studio and linked my AppHarbor account to the github.

It restores the nuget packages as shown below but fails when building. I can compile (and run) it without any problems on my own pc.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this, or what I might be doing wrong?

Time    Message
1/16/17 10:39 AM    Received notification, queuing build
1/16/17 10:39 AM    Downloading source
1/16/17 10:39 AM    Downloaded source in 0.1 seconds
1/16/17 10:39 AM    Starting NuGet package restore
1/16/17 10:39 AM    NuGet package restore completed
1/16/17 10:39 AM    Starting build
1/16/17 10:39 AM    Build failed: An error occurred during the build

Build started 1/16/2017 9:39:42 AM.
     1>Project "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
     1>Project "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>PrepareForBuild:
         Creating directory "obj\Release\".
     2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3257: The primary reference "System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a higher version "4.1.2.0" than exists in the current target framework. The version found in the current target framework is "4.0.0.0". [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]
     2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3257: The primary reference "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a higher version "4.1.1.0" than exists in the current target framework. The version found in the current target framework is "4.0.0.0". [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]
     2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3257: The primary reference "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a higher version "4.1.0.0" than exists in the current target framework. The version found in the current target framework is "4.0.10.0". [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]
     2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3323: Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store. [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]
     2>Done Building Project "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

```
   "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
   (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 
     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3257: The primary reference "System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a higher version "4.1.2.0" than exists in the current target framework. The version found in the current target framework is "4.0.0.0". [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]
     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3257: The primary reference "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a higher version "4.1.1.0" than exists in the current target framework. The version found in the current target framework is "4.0.0.0". [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]
     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3257: The primary reference "System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a higher version "4.1.0.0" than exists in the current target framework. The version found in the current target framework is "4.0.10.0". [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]


   "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
   (ResolveKeySource target) -> 
     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2482,5): error MSB3323: Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store. [D:\temp\rp5gvmbn.own\input\DiscordBot\DiscordBot.csproj]

3 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and install back your nuget packages for Discord. Make sure the versions of other packages matches for the one that discord required too as well as making sure that required packages are present.

Comment: This managed to solve my problem, mind you I removed ALL nuget references and readded just enough that I didn't have any errors anymore. The bonus is that I dropped down to like 60% of the references I had at first and no more errors on app-harbor ;D

Comment: Mostly to put it : if you see errors that contains `The primary reference....could not be resolved because it has a higher version "4.1.2.0" than exists in the current target framework.` It means that the API package requires a certain version of another package to work. Discord.NET currently does not work with the lastest Json build. So check required versions of other API packages before updating. (Some of them clashes too, ex. One requires a newer version, one requires older. That one is extremely hard to fix. In those cases, try to use a different package or something.)

Comment: Wen my problem actually got fixed because I removed all the references and the ones that were giving me shit were the ones that I didn't need xD I guess I did something which needed them at one point and then removed the code but the references didn't get dropped :p And yeah I had been updating each time there was an update available but I'll stop doing that since I've got a working application now :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of the old MSBuild version (supplied with .NET `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`).

When I installed [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) and switched to it (`"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`) everything went well.